# file_get_contents returns an empty string that is 354 bytes long

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I'm trying to read the contents of a file and simply getting an empty string. The file exists on the server.

I've tried some test with the following code and get the true to display:

```
$filename = "includes/blah.php";

$filecontents = file_get_contents($filename, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);

if ($filecontents === false) {

echo(":FALSE:");

}

else {

echo(":TRUE:");

}

var_dump($filecontents);
```

The dump displays "string(354)" which is the correct size of the file.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What encoding does the file use? Is it UTF-8? UTF-16?

Comment: What are you expecting to happen here? (I'm presuming it prints ":TRUE:" before the var_dump?) Also, are you sure the file doesn't contain non-printing characters in whatever encoding you're using for output?

Answer (score 0):

Check

1. permissions on file (r for webserver)
2. error reporting at server
3. wrap output with htmlentities()

(add error_reporting(E_ALL) on top of your script)

regards,

///t

Comment: There are no errors being reported anywhere. I've set the reporting level. Here's another bit of code that works, except for the var_dump:

<?php
include_once 'includes/blah.php';

function validateStep() {

 $tblPrefix = $_POST["tblPrefix"];

 $filename = "includes/blah.php";
 $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
 $contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
 fclose($handle);

var_dump($contents);
 $handle = fopen($filename, "w");
 $newContents = str_replace("___tblPrefix___", $tblPrefix, $contents, $count);
 $count = fwrite($handle, $newContents);
 fclose($handle);  

 return "";
}